# Is total variation additive?

Tags: real-analysis

Definition. The total variation of $F$ on $[a,x]$ (where $a\leq x\leq b$) is defined by $$T_F(a,x) = \sup\sum_{j=1}^N|F(t_j)-F(t_{j-1})|$$
where the sup is over all partitions of $[a,x]$.

here, we assume $F$ is real-valued function.

Under this definition, if $a\leq c\leq b$, then $T_F(a,c)+T_F(c,b) = T_F(a,b)$?

Comment: The answer is positive. It follows from definition by direct  checking.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Well $\leq$ is also direct to me. But $\geq$ is not direct to me. Could you explain?

Comment: You say $\leq$ is clear so ill try give you an idea for $\geq$. By definition of $sup$ you can find a finite sequence in $(a,b)$ that is $\epsilon$ close to $T_F(a,b)$ then modify this sequence (if needed) to have two valid sequences in both $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ then by the triangle inequality $T_F(a,c)+T_F(c,b)+\epsilon \geq T_F(a,b)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the part you're missing: Take any partition $(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_N)$ of $[a,b]$ and consider the sum $$\sum_{j=1}^N|F(t_j)-F(t_{j-1})|$$ for that particular partition. Make a new partition by inserting $c$ at the suitable place, and see what happens to the sum.